# Distance from point to box boundary

Tags: python, numpy, distance, euclidean-distance

In a game I'm writing with *Pygame*, I have a 2D point `(x,y)` in a box from `(0,0)` to `(1,1)` (perfect square with side length 1).
I want to calculate the euclidean distance from the point to the box boundary in a direction `alpha`, where `alpha` is an azimuth direction measured in radians counter-clockwise, starting from `alpha=0` as the x-axis direction.

I wrote a python code that calculates this distance, but I'm not sure it's the most efficient/cleanest way:

```py
import numpy as np


def get_distance_to_boundary(x, y, angle):
    cos_angle, sin_angle = np.cos(angle), np.sin(angle)
    if cos_angle == 0:
        return y if sin_angle < 0 else 1 - y
    if sin_angle == 0:
        return x if cos_angle < 0 else 1 - x
    x_target = 1 if cos_angle > 0 else 0
    y_target = y + (x_target - x) * np.tan(angle)
    if y_target > 1:
        return np.fabs((1 - y) / sin_angle)
    if y_target < 0:
        return np.fabs(y / sin_angle)
    return np.sqrt((x_target - x) ** 2 + (y_target - y) ** 2)
```

Any idea for a better approach?

Illustration:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This method is a little more efficient/cleaner because you don't need  `tan`, `fabs`, `sqrt` or `**2`:

```py
def distance(x,y,angle):
    cos_angle, sin_angle = np.cos(angle), np.sin(angle)
    if cos_angle == 0:
        return y if sin_angle < 0 else 1 - y
    if sin_angle == 0:
        return x if cos_angle < 0 else 1 - x
    distance_EW = (1-x)/cos_angle if cos_angle>0 else -x/cos_angle
    distance_NS = (1-y)/sin_angle if sin_angle>0 else -y/sin_angle
    return min(distance_EW, distance_NS)
```

I define `distance_EW` as the distance in the case where the target is on the East wall (if cos_angle>0) or on the West wall (if cos_angle<0). Similarly, define `distance_NS` for the North or South wall.

...

**WARNING:** My distance function will sometimes produce different results than your function because of rounding errors!! This is especially problematic when your starting point is at the border of the box and `angle` is close to a multiple of π/2.
I would suggest you set some sort of tolerance like `if abs(sin_angle) < 1e-12:`, instead of `if sin_angle == 0:`. That way, `sin_angle = np.sin(np.pi)` will be accepted in the  `if` condition, even though it is not exactly equal to 0 (because `np.sin(np.pi)` is `1.2e-16` with python).

Comment: Side note: If you love making your code illegible just like me, then you can define the distances more succinctly: `distance_EW = ((cos_angle>0)-x)/cos_angle` and `distance_NS = ((sin_angle>0)-y)/sin_angle`.  (Don't actually do this if other people have to read your code too)